# Unable to run Raven Studio from ASP.NET 5 web application

Tags: ravendb, asp.net-core

I have created a new web application using ASP.NET 5 RC1 with RavenDb. I am having trouble determining how to bring up the Raven Studio web client. In Chrome, I can see the following JSON response:

```
{
   "Message": "The following embedded file was not available: index.html. Please make sure that the Raven.Studio.Html5.zip file exist in the main directory (near to the Raven.Database.dll)."
}
```

Seems straight forward, however, this presents two issues. First, I don't find the specified zip file in my project anywhere nor have I been able to find it in the RavenDb GitHub repo or anywhere else on the web. Additionally, since ASP.NET vNext has a drastically different approach to project organization, I am not sure how this requirement translates. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the Raven.Studio.zip file in the same place?

Comment: What specifically does "the same place" mean? I added it to the root of the project. Is that where it needs to be?

Comment: @AyendeRahien I've tried including `Raven.Studio.Html5.zip` in many different locations within the project folder as well as the new `artifacts` directory but none seem to satisfy. Can you please share what the requirement is for accessing Raven Studio for an embedded db instance using an ASP.NET 5 web app?

Comment: It should be in the web directory, next to the web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Success! In order to get Raven Studio working with an ASP.NET 5 project, you need to put the `Raven.Studio.Html5.zip` file in the `wwwroot` directory.